# Integral closure of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{n}]$ if $n$ is not square-free

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I need to find the integral closure of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{n}]$.

The first step is: **Reduce to the case where $n$ is square free.**

Not really sure how to go about this. If $n$ is not square-free, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Write $n=q^2 d$ where $d$ is square free. Then $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt n) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$. Let $\cal O$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb Z$ in $K$. Then $\cal O$ is also the integral closure of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt n]$ in $K$ because $\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb Z[\sqrt n] \subseteq \cal O$and $\cal O$ is integrally closed:
$$
{\cal O} = IC(\mathbb Z)  \subseteq IC(\mathbb Z[\sqrt n]) \subseteq IC({\cal O})={\cal O}
$$

Comment: At this point of the exercise, we don't have any of this information. Is there a way to reduce to the $n$ square-free case without all the machinery?

Comment: @AlJebr, which information don't you have? The only real point is that $\cal O$ is integrally closed, but that is almost by definition.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by double inclusion? Showing that the integral closure of $\mathbb Z[q\sqrt{d}]$ is contained in the integral closure of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is straightforward. Can we show the reverse inclusion?